# Firefox 35 network monitor, don't merge same-name http header, can I?

Tags: firefox, http

I'm using Firefox 35 to debug HTTP protocol, but find some weird thing.

The server response header is:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Tue, 27 Jan 2015 06:12:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.27 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1j DAV/2 SVN/1.8.11 mod_auth_sspi/1.0.4
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="SSPI realm (SSPIOfferBasic On)"
Content-Length: 401
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

But firefox merges the two `WWW-Authenticate:` lines so it looks quite misleading(screen shot below). Is there a way to fix this? (perhaps some secret configuration tweak)

I've tried extension like httpfox, and it exhibits the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Bugs generally aren't configurable...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. it is compliance with [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html)

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

Comment: Two quick question: (1) *if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list* -- does ``WWW-Authenticate`` header meet this characteristic?. (2) Could you cite some typical headers with such characteristic?

Comment: (1) No, a `WWW-Authenticate` value may contain a comma (2) I think `Content-Type` is a header with comma-seperated values

Comment: If so, Firefox display(my underline in the image) is a bug, because it should display ``WWW-Authenticate`` in two separate lines, right?